# Resize braces arbitrarily

Tags: braces, inkscape

I'm trying to get arbitrarily big braces in some graphs I have to make, using Inkscape with the PDF+LaTeX option. The problem I have is that simply resizing a bracket makes it stretch:

[image]

I'm aware that this may sound like an Inkscape question, but I'm trying to solve it with LaTeX (as opposed to a vector graphic approach).

So, is there a way to arbitrarily "resize" the brackets without deforming themspelling? I'm thinking about the end result of the `align` environment (vertical) or `overbrace`/`underbrace` (horizontal), but without really using any content to expand it (hence, arbitrarily). Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\left\{ \rule{0pt}{4cm} \right.  %Change size as necessary
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: brace]

You can use something similar for the horizontal version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\rule{8cm}{0pt}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: brace2]

Note that the height of the vertical version is double the height of the rule, whereas for the horizontal version the rule and the brace have the same length.

Comment: To get an invisible vertical rule -- a "strut" in typographic jargon -- that's 8 cm tall in all and extends 4 cm below and above the baseline, on would need to type `\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{8cm}`.